# How to send message/data from android to chrome browser?

Tags: android, web-services, google-chrome

I want to send some data from my phone to chrome browser. For that i am using Google App Engine as a server. And at browser end i am building chrome extension which will poll server for new msg or would implement PUSH.

But i am getting confused , what if 1000 users are using the same service.How will messages/data will be delivered to correct user?

I am thinking of using userid (Oauth) through which each user will login from android and browser both.

So i got few questions for that:
How can i route correct msg to each user? 
Should i store userid on server along with their unsync msges for each user?

Is this approach correct? OR their is some better way?

Comment: App Engine scales fine for read access but rather bad for write access. It might not be suitable for your application.